# update a json file data using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have one json file. I am getting json file data through http.get() method and storing into one scope variable. Now I am modifying the json file data as I want. How to pass the parameters to through http.post()  and update json file data.

```
    $http.get('/HCConfig/ValidityReminderSettings.json').then(function (response,data)                     $scope.value=console.log(response.data.ValidityReminderSettings);
$scope.reminder1 = response.data.ValidityReminderSettings.Reminder1;
$scope.reminder2 = response.data.ValidityReminderSettings.Reminder2;
    });
```

Json file looks like:

```
"ValidityReminderSettings": 
{ 
   "Reminder1" : "30",
   "Reminder2" : "15"      
}
```

I am passing parameters that I need to update into json file

```
$scope.UpdateValidityReminderSettings =function()
{
    var newremainderVal1=document.getElementById('Reminder1').value; 
    var newremainderVal2=document.getElementById('Reminder2').value;

    $scope.ArrayValue=[{"Reminder1":newremainderVal1},
                         {"Reminder2":newremainderVal2}];
    var  datas= $scope.ArrayValue;
    $http.put('/updateJsonFile' + datas).then(function (response) 
   {
          $scope.ServerResponse = data;
   });
```

}
    In server page how should I pass this and update that json file

```
var jsonfileConfig = require('./public/HCConfig/ValidityReminderSettings.json');
```

app.put('/updateJsonFile/:data',jsonfileConfig);

I am getting error. I am doing something wrong while passing this parameters in server page. How to pass and update this json file

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **+** (plus) and use **,** (comma) in post request

Example:

```
$http.post('/updateJsonFile' , {"data":datas}).then
```

It looks like you are using nodejs on server side..

```
app.post('/updateJsonFile/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.data);
    fs.writeFile('./public/HCConfig/ValidityReminderSettings.jso‌​n', req.body.data);
});
```

You can use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) package to write json to file

Comment: app.post('/updateJsonFile/', data); Referrence error in server page data is not defined

Comment: i am not writing new json file. I am updating the existing json file values. Now I have used $htttp.put() even though i am getting error

Comment: I have updated code... previous code was just for giving idea.. now I have improved code on angular and nodejs... on server you will get json in req.body.data.

Comment: in console.log(req.body.data) I am getting whatever I changed in reminder1 and reminder2 but it is not updating in that file .  fs.writeFile('./public/HCConfig/ValidityReminderSettings.jso‌​n', req.body.data); I think this line is not working.

Comment: Use following code and inform me what you get on console

`fs.writeFile('./public/HCConfig/ValidityReminderSettings.jso‌​‌​n', req.body.data , 'utf8', function(err,data) {`
       `if (err){`
           `console.log(err);`
       `};`
       `res.end(data);`
    `}); `

Comment: In command prompt It displaying updated value but in  $http.put('/updateJsonFile' + datas).then(function (response) 
   {
          $scope.ServerResponse = data;
   }); ServerResponse has " " data. And it is also creating a new json file with this name with [object:object] [object:object] data

Comment: response is empty because we are not returning correct data... Plz replace `res.end(data);` with `res.end(req.body.data);`.

Comment: and to solve **[object:object] [object:object]**, replace `req.body.data` with `JSON.stringify(req.body.data)`. It might solve your problem